# What is the meaning of these lines in the opening of Elfen Lied?

Tags: theme-song, elfen-lied

In the opening of *Elfen Lied* titled *Lilium*, there are these lines:

1. > Kyrie, fons bonitatis.

   What is the meaning of "fountain of holiness"? Where they dedicating?
2. > Kyrie, ignis divine, eleison.

   Who is or what is "ignis divine"?

Are these words just air or contain some deep meaning?

Answer (score 4):

To give you some context, this song is sung in Latin and "Kyrie" is the a common prayer in Christian liturgy. "Kyrie eleison" pretty much equates to "lord, have mercy".

If you look at [some translations](https://lyrics.az/elfen-lied/-/lilium.html) of these lyrics we see the two lines in question roughly translated as:

> Lord, spring of goodness.
> Lord, heavenly fire, have mercy.

So to answer your question, this *prayer* is a fixed expression praising the Lord.
In the Christian context, these words are not "just air" and have [history](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40916/is-the-term-kyrie-eleison-latin-or-greek) and [meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyrie). In the context of *Elfen Lied*, the connection is more tenuous.

Comment: Catholic prayers, actually. Most Catholics(as I am one) use those. "Kyrie eleison" is actually a Greek transliteration. It can be used sometimes as Latin.